# commutative diagram of abelian subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f:G\to H$ be a homomorphism of groups, show that there is a unique $f_{ab}:G_{ab}\to H_{ab}$ so that the diagram bellow is commutative, then show that if $f$ is surjective, so is $f_{ab}$.

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} G@>{f}>> H\\ @VVV @VVV \\ G_{ab} @>{f_{ab}}>> H_{ab}; \end{CD}$$

For the first part my idea was to use the homomorphism theorem and set $G_2=H_{ab}$.  If we take $N=[G,G]$ we get the given map. Because $G_{ab}$ and $H_{ab}$ are abelian $f_{ab}$ must be commutative. All we need to do is to prove that $f_{ab}$ is unique. We define the canonic mapping $\varphi:G\to G_{ab}$, we see then that $\varphi:H\to H_{ab}$ thus there is a $f\circ\varphi =\varphi\circ f_{ab}$?? I don't know what to do... Am I just writing gibberish?

For the surjective part I thought I'd assume that $f_{ab}$ is not surjective then  there would be a $h\in H_{ab}$ so that $\varphi(f_{ab}(g))\neq h$ for all $h$ in $H_{ab}$ but because $f\circ\varphi=\varphi\circ f_{ab}$ this is a contradiction? Please help me. I need to finish these proofs

Comment: Is $\;G.ab\;$ the abelianization $\;G/G'\;$ of $\;G\;$ ?

Comment: yes, I just didn't know how to get ab beneath G so I put at dot infront of ab

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad formulation but I'm new to this

Comment: Bob, use _ = lower hyphen

Comment: What do you mean by "$f_{ab}$ must be commutative" ?

Comment: @Arthur why would I have to assume that $H$ is abelian? and why does $f' $go to $H$ and not $H_{ab}$

Comment: @CaptainLama you tell me, I'm quoting the assignment

Comment: Perhaps a remark : this is not a diagram of "abelian" "sub"groups, but just a commutative diagram of "groups". They are not all abelian nor subgroups of some group.

Comment: @Bob, you seem to misunderstand the assignment : the diagram has to be commutative, which has nothing to do with the fact than any group is abelian (it just means that the two ways of composing arrows along the square give the same morphism). A morphism being "commutative" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Define the canonical projections $\;\pi_G:G\to G/G'\;,\;\;\pi_H:H\to H/H'\;$ , and define

$$f_{ab}:G/G'\to H/H'\;,\;\;f_{ab}(xG'):=f(x)H'$$

First, $\;f_{ab}\;$ is well defined since ( check that $\;f(G')\le f(H')\;(*)\;$)

$$xG'=yG'\implies y^{-1}x\in G'\stackrel{(*)}\implies f(y^{-1}x)=f(y)^{-1}f(x)\in H'\implies f(x)H'=f(y)H'$$

also:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet\;&f_{ab}\pi_G(x)=f_{ab}(xG'):=f(x)H'\\{}\\\bullet\;&\pi_Hf(x)=f(x)H'\end{align*}$$

and we have our commutative diagram.

If $\;f\;$ is surjective then for any $\;h\in H\;\exists\,x_h\in G\;\;\text{such that}\;\;f(x_h)=h\;$ , so for any $\;yH'\in H/H'\;$ let $\;x_y\in G\;$ be so that $\;f(x_y)=y\;$ , and

$$f_{ab}x_yG':=f(x_y)H'=yH'$$

and $\;f_{ab}\;$ is surjective, too.

Uniqueness follows, I think, from the fact that for any set of generators of $\;G\;$ the homomorphism $\;f\;$, and thus also $\;f_{ab}\;$ , is uniquely determined by its action on that set.

Comment: Is it okay if I substitute $G'$ for $[G,G]$. What happens if I say that $f$ is injective by the way? Does this also imply that $f_{ab}$ is injective? @Joanpemo

Comment: @Bob I'm not sure about injectivity yet I tried something and didn't succeed, so I think it isn't true since $\;f(x)\in H'\;$ doesn't necessarily mean, I believe, that $\;x\in G'\;$ ,which is what's need for injectivity.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical maps are surjective, hence if $ f $ is surjective, the upper way from $ G $ to $ H_{\text{ab}} $ is too. As the diagram is commutative, the lower way is surjective. Hence the lower horizontal map, $ f_{\text{ab}} $ is surjective, by a well known result on sets.

Answer (score 0):

You have a homomorphism $\varphi_H\circ f:G\to H_{ab}$ where $H_{ab}$ is abelian. Show that there is an $f_{ab}:G_{ab}\to H_{ab}$ such that $f = f_{ab}\circ \varphi_G$. (Hint: compare the commutator subgroup of $G$ and the kernel of $f$).

For uniqueness, assume that there is another map $g_{ab}:G_{ab}\to H_{ab}$ that makes the diagram commute. That means that there must be an $aG' \in G_{ab}$ (remember that $G_{ab}$ is a *quotient* of $G$ by $G'$, the commutator subgroup of $G$, hence that notation) such that $f_{ab}(aG') \neq g_{ab}(aG')$. Derive a contradiction using $\varphi_H(f(a))$ and commutativity of the diagram.

For the second part, assume $f$ is surjective. We know that $\varphi_G$ and $\varphi_H$ are surjective, being quotient maps. Therefore, $f_{ab}\circ \varphi_G = \varphi_H\circ f$ is surjective as well. But a composition of two functions cannot be surjective unless the second component of said composition is. Therefore $f_{ab}$ is surjective too (you might have to show this as well, it is true in general for any functions on any sets, not just homomorphisms between groups).